# open new activity from spinner selectedItem

Tags: android, android-intent, android-spinner

What's wrong in this code?  I couldn't view the selected item into to the second view?

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2
, long arg3){

int Index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();

                Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(),
                        arg0.getItemAtPosition(Index).toString() + " View Selected",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent newIntent = new Intent(GazaGuideSample.this, GuideCategories.class);
                newIntent.putExtra("text",arg0.getItemAtPosition(Index).toString());
                startActivity(newIntent);

            }
```

Comment: Can you post logcat message with error?

Comment: Can you not use arg2 as the index?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mYourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()     
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id)
            {                           
                //int Index = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();pos - is SelectedPosition

        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                pos + " View Selected",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent newIntent = new Intent(GazaGuideSample.this, GuideCategories.class);
        newIntent.putExtra("text",pos.toString());
        startActivity(newIntent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
            {           
            }           
        });
```

Comment: nothing happend !!!!!!! public class GuideCategories extends Activity {
  protected void onCreat(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.guidecategories);
   
   TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   tv.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Your Selected Item is : " + "text"));
 
}
}

Comment: Have you registered your GuideCategories in AndroidManifest?